# recycelrview adapter last item is not updating after deleting using retrofit , i am using interface because have to pass product id

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Activity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getCartList();

}
private void getCartList() {
    showProgressDialog();

    Call<List<CartList>> call = api.getCartList(1);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CartList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<CartList>> call, Response<List<CartList>> response) {
            cartLists = response.body();
            if (cartLists.size() == 0) {
                tvCartEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressDialog.cancel();
            } else {
                addToCartAdapter.setData(cartLists);
                productList.setAdapter(addToCartAdapter);
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<CartList>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(AddToCartActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
@Override
public void deleteItemID(int id) {
    Call<CartList> deleteCall = api.deleteCartItem(id);
    deleteCall.enqueue(new Callback<CartList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CartList> call, Response<CartList> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "deleteItem by id" + response.code());
            onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CartList> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

i mean last is deleting but not updating on the spot even though i called onresume in delete item method.
i have to open that activity again to see updted result

i hope i will get my query solved soon!
thanks
if you want i will upload inteface and adapter code. which i do not think necessary here.

**Solution**

just had to add this in response class

```
public void onResponse(Call<List<CartList>> call, Response<List<CartList>> response) {
            cartLists = response.body();
            if (cartLists.size() == 0) {
                tvCartEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvCartItems.setText("0 items");
                addToCartAdapter.setData(cartLists);
                progressDialog.cancel();
            } else {
                addToCartAdapter.setData(cartLists);
                productList.setAdapter(addToCartAdapter);
                tvCartItems.setText(cartLists.size() + " Items");
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to call onResume() again.

instead of that you should use the following snippet:

```
cartLists.removeAt(id);
addToCartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

your deleteItem function would look like below code:

```
@Override
public void deleteItemID(int id) {
Call<CartList> deleteCall = api.deleteCartItem(id);
deleteCall.enqueue(new Callback<CartList>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<CartList> call, Response<CartList> response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "deleteItem by id" + response.code());
        cartLists.removeAt(id);
        addToCartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<CartList> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: look at the solution I just added to my question worked!!!